# Scroll to next or previous elements

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, scrollbar

I have a scroller that contains max 3 elements and has down arrow to go down to next elements and up arrow to go back to previous elements but i'm having trouble making it work.

Here is snippet of html:

```
<div class="mob-keys-container" id="mob-keys-container">
    <img id="mob-icon-up" src="./images/mob-up-btn.png" alt="down" width="40px">
     <div id="icon-container">
        <img class="answerIcon mobIcon active" draggable="true" id="answer_1_mob" src="./images/5.1.png" alt="key">
        <img class="answerIcon mobIcon active" draggable="true" id="answer_2_mob" src="./images/5.2.png" alt="key">
        <img class="answerIcon mobIcon active" draggable="true" id="answer_3_mob" src="./images/5.3.png" alt="key">
        <img class="answerIcon mobIcon active" draggable="true" id="answer_4_mob" src="./images/5.4.png" alt="key">
        <img class="answerIcon mobIcon active" draggable="true" id="answer_5_mob" src="./images/5.5.png" alt="key">
        <img class="answerIcon mobIcon active" draggable="true" id="answer_6_mob" src="./images/5.6.png" alt="key">
     </div>
    <img id="mob-icon-down" src="./images/mob-down-btn.png" alt="down" width="40px">
 </div>
```

and here is JQuery:

```
$('#mob-icon-down').on('click', () => {
// finds visible elements(max 3)
        let $visible = $('.mobIcon:visible');
// finds first element
        let $firstVisible = $visible.first();
// finds last element
        let $lastVisible = $visible.last();
// find next element
        let $nextVisible = $lastVisible.next();
// hides scroller arrow if there are less than 3 elements
        if ($visible.length < 3) {
            $('#mob-icon-down').hide();
        } else {
            $firstVisible.hide();
            $nextVisible.show();
        }

    })

    $('#mob-icon-up').on('click', () => {
// finds visible elements(max 3)
        let $visible = $('.mobIcon:visible');
// finds first element
        let $firstVisible = $visible.first();
// finds last element
        let $lastVisible = $visible.last();
// finds element before the first
        let $prevVisible = $firstVisible.prev();
// hides scroller arrow if there are less than 3 elements
        if ($visible.length < 3) {
            $('#mob-icon-up').hide();
        } else {
            $lastVisible.hide();
            $prevVisible.show();
        }

    })
```

The corresponging arrows should disappear when there are no next/previous elements and reappear if this changes but it's a mess right now and element count breaks after it hits a wall and all that is left are no elements and no arrows.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet which shows the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear how this should work. You talk about max 3 elements, but have 6 in your example. You do not scroll to them but hide/show them. And all have the class "active" so Im assuming all are visible at the start? The functionality seems more like a slider than a scrolling container. Anyways, what is definitevely missing: you are not keeping track of the currently active element. It should start with 1 active element and that should change when ascending / descending through the elements.

Comment: There are 10 elements in total but only  max 3 elements are shown on the screen and that is achieved with css nth child help by giving all elements dispaly none and only showing the first 3. Nothing happens until the user clicks up or down arrow showing next or prev element and hiding the element that is left out. When there are no more prev elements, the up arrow should dissapear un when there are no more next elements, the down button should be gone. In this situation, scroller just gets rid of elements when in hits the wall untill there are none left. 'Active' class was to track but failed

Answer (score 1):

```js
// move up
function up() {
    //all currently active elements
  let $active = $('.image.active');
  // last active element
  let $last = $active.last();
  // element before those in the list
  let $prev = $active.prev();
  // remove active class from last/bottom element 
  $last.removeClass('active');
  // add active class to previous element
  $prev.addClass('active');
  check();
}

function down() {
    // exactly as up() just in the other direction
  let $active = $('.image.active');
  let $first = $active.first();
  let $next = $active.next();
  $first.removeClass('active');
  $next.addClass('active');
  check();
}

function check() {
    // all image elements
    let $images = $('.image');
  let $active = $('.image.active');
  let $first = $active.first();
  let $last = $active.last();
    // if the last element is the last image, disable the down button
  if($last.index() === $images.length - 1) {
    $('#moveDown').attr('disabled', true);
  }else{
  // otherwise, enable it
    $('#moveDown').attr('disabled', false);
  }
  
  // if the first active element is the first image, disable the up button
  if($first.index() === 0) {
    $('#moveUp').attr('disabled', true);
  }else{
  // otherwise enable it
    $('#moveUp').attr('disabled', false);
  }
}

function init(elementsToShow ) {
  // set active class on the first 3 elements
  $('.image').slice(0, elementsToShow).addClass('active');
  // set the up Button to disabled
  $('#moveUp').attr('disabled', true);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // init the container with max number of elments to show
  init( 3 );
})
```

```css
.btn-group {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CECECE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: none;
}

.image.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button onClick="down()" id="moveDown">
    DOWN
  </button>
  <button onClick="up()" id="moveUp">
    UP
  </button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>3</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>4</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>5</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>6</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>7</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>8</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>9</h1></div>
  <div class="image"><h1>10</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks!

Just one problem that I guess I didn't specify that these images are draggable elements that get appended from DOM when they reach the target and these functions kinda of break after that because there are only 2 elements left with 'active' class. Is it possible to somehow give the next element in line the class 'active' when one of the elements on dispaly gets appended?

Comment: Afaik there should be an `onDrop` event (or similar) that you could trigger on your container element and then adjust whatever you need adjusted when you drop a new element in your container.